# Difficulty Increasing Reward in DQN Training for Atari Breakout

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm currently working on training a Deep Q-Network (DQN) to play Atari Breakout using Python and TensorFlow. Despite numerous attempts and adjustments to the network architecture , now a run the code but total reward is zero how i can rewrite this crap to work
I've experimented with various reward shaping techniques, adjusted exploration strategies, and fine-tuned the network architecture, yet the reward remains stagnant. I suspect the issue might be related to the reward design or possibly the network's ability to learn
and i wanna why so wrong

```
import gym 
from random import shuffle
import cv2
from PER import *
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn as nn

class CNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_shape, num_actions):
    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input_shape[0], 32, kernel_size=8, stride=4)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
    
    # Calculating the input size for the fully connected layer
    conv_output_size = self._get_conv_output(input_shape)
    
    self.fc = nn.Linear(conv_output_size, 512)
    self.output = nn.Linear(512, num_actions)

def forward(self, x):
    x = x / 255.0  # Normalize input
    x = x.float()  # Convert to float tensor
    x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
    x = torch.relu(self.conv3(x))
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Flatten the tensor
    x = torch.relu(self.fc(x))
    x = self.output(x)
    return x

def _get_conv_output(self, shape):
    dummy_input = torch.zeros(1, *shape)
    dummy_output = self._forward_conv(dummy_input)
    return int(dummy_output.view(dummy_output.size(0), -1).size(1))

def _forward_conv(self, x):
    x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
    x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
    x = torch.relu(self.conv3(x))
    return x

   class Dqn_Cnn:
     def __init__(self,env_name):

    self.env_name = env_name
    self.env = gym.make(env_name,render_mode="rgb_array")
    self.ROWS = 84
    self.COLS =  84
    self.REM_STEP = 4 #frames 
    self.EPISODES = 10
    self.state_size = self.env.observation_space.shape[0]
    self.action_size = self.env.action_space.n
    self.MEMORY = Memory(memory)
    self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
    self.USE_PER = True
    self.gamma = 0.9
    self.epsilon = 1.0  # exploration probability at start
    self.epsilon_min = 0.01  # minimum exploration probability 
    self.epsilon_decay = 0.0005  # exponential decay rate for exploration prob
    self.N = 500 #A
    self.batch_size = 500 #B
    self.memory_1 = [] 
    self.counter = 0
    #self.batch_size = 32
    self.counter = 0

    # defining model parameters
    self.ddqn = True # use doudle deep q network
    self.Soft_Update = False # use soft parameter update
    
    self.epsilon_greedy = False # use epsilon greedy strategy
    self.USE_PER = True # use priority experienced replay
    
    self.TAU = 0.1 # target network soft update hyperparameter
    
    
    self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    self.model = CNN(input_shape=(self.REM_STEP, self.ROWS, self.COLS), num_actions=self.action_size)
    self.target_model = CNN(input_shape=(self.REM_STEP, self.ROWS, self.COLS), num_actions=self.action_size)
    self.target_model.load_state_dict(self.model.state_dict())
    self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    self.model.to(self.device)
    self.target_model.to(self.device)
   #self.Save_Path = 'Models'
   #if not os.path.exists(self.Save_Path): os.makedirs(self.Save_Path)
    #elf.scores, self.episodes, self.average = [], [], []


        
    

    self.image_memory = np.zeros((self.REM_STEP, self.ROWS, self.COLS))
    
def update_target_model(self):
    self.target_model.load_state_dict(self.model.state_dict())

def choose_action(self, state):
    # Epsilon-greedy strategy for action selection
    if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
        return self.env.action_space.sample()  # Choose a random action
    else:
        # Choose the action with the highest Q-value from the model
        state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)
        q_values = self.model(state)
        return q_values.argmax().item() 

def imshow(self,image,rem_step=0):
    cv2.imshow(env_name+str(rem_step) , image[rem_step,...])
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        return 

def GetImage(self):
    img = self.env.render()

    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    img_rgb_resized = cv2.resize(img_rgb, (self.COLS, self.ROWS), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
   
# Normalize pixel values between 0 and 1
    img_rgb_resized = img_rgb_resized.astype(np.float32) / 255.0

    self.image_memory = np.roll(self.image_memory, 1, axis=0)
    self.image_memory[0, :, :] = img_rgb_resized
    self.imshow(self.image_memory,0)
    return np.expand_dims(self.image_memory, axis=0)     

       #image vai para escala cinza 

def add(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
    self.counter +=1
    if self.counter % 500 == 0: #C
        self.shuffle_memory()
        
    if len(self.memory) < self.N: #D
        self.memory.append( (state, action, reward, next_state) )
    else:
        rand_index = np.random.randint(0,self.N-1)
        self.memory[rand_index] = (state, action, reward,next_state )
    
def shuffle_memory(self): #E
       shuffle(self.memory)
def get_batch(self): #F
    if len(self.memory) < self.batch_size:
        batch_size = len(self.memory)
    else:
        batch_size = self.batch_size
    if len(self.memory) < 1:
        print("Error: No data in memory.")
        return None
    #G
    ind = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(self.memory)),batch_size,replace=False)
    batch = [self.memory[i] for i in ind] #batch is a list of tuples
    state_batch = torch.stack([x[0].squeeze() for x in batch],dim=0)
    action_batch = torch.Tensor([x[1] for x in batch]).long()
    reward_batch = torch.Tensor([x[2] for x in batch])
    next_state_batch = torch.stack([x[3].squeeze() for x in batch], dim=0)
    return state_batch, action_batch, reward_batch, next_state_batch
   
    
def reset(self):
    for i in range(self.REM_STEP):
        state = self.env.reset()
    return state

def step(self,action):
    next_state, reward, done, info, *_ = self.env.step(action)
    next_state = self.GetImage()
    return next_state, reward, done, info


def run(self):
     
     for episode in range(self.EPISODES):
        self.reset()
        total_reward = 0
        done = False  # Reset done flag for each episode

        episode_rewards = []  # Initialize episode_rewards list
        for t in range(500):
            state = self.GetImage()

            action = self.choose_action(state)
            next_state, reward, done, info = self.step(action)  
            state = torch.from_numpy(state).to(self.device)
            next_state = torch.from_numpy(next_state)
            state = next_state
            self.add( state, action, reward, next_state)  
            batch = self.get_batch()
            if batch is not None:
                state_batch, action_batch, reward_batch, next_state_batch = batch

            # Convert batch to tensors
                state_batch = state_batch.to(self.device)
                action_batch = action_batch.to(self.device)
                reward_batch = reward_batch.to(self.device)
                next_state_batch = next_state_batch.to(self.device)

                q_values = self.model(state_batch)
               # next_q_values = self.target_model(next_state_batch)
            
            # Gather Q-values for predicted actions
                q_values = q_values.gather(1, action_batch.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
            
            # Calculate target Q-values using Double DQN formula
                next_actions = torch.argmax(self.model(next_state_batch), dim=1)
                next_q_values_target = self.target_model(next_state_batch).gather(1, next_actions.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
                target_q_values = reward_batch + self.gamma * next_q_values_target * (1 - done)
            
            # Calculate loss and update the model
                loss = nn.MSELoss()(q_values, target_q_values.detach())
                self.optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                self.optimizer.step()
            
            # Optionally update target network periodically
            
                if self.ddqn and t % self.TAU == 0:
                    self.update_target_model() 
        
         
        total_reward += reward
        episode_rewards.append(total_reward)  # Append total reward for this episode
        print(f"Episode {episode + 1}/{self.EPISODES} - Total Reward: {total_reward}")
        


  env_name="ALE/Breakout-ram-v5" 

 agent = Dqn_Cnn(env_name)
 agent.run()
```